# Using Wt with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, wt

I'm working on a project to develop a web application for controlling some machinery and visualising sensor data. It is deployed on a single board computer running a custom linux distro.  We have a large existing code base from a previous version of the project that is based on a standalone Qt app. With the new software we are moving towards a web based interface using [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/).

At the moment we are trying to re-use the Qt code which interfaces with some system services, while hosting and interfacing with the new Wt GUI. The Qt app and Wt app are launched on different threads. Wt on the main thread and Qt on another thread. Using the c++ "thread" library to do so.

I have very little experience in Qt and there seems to be very little existing documentation on integrating the two, does anyone know of any conflicts that may occur between Wt and Qt in general, or specific to this situation.

So far it seems to be running ok and playing nicely, but I am simply trying to cover all my bases. I am looking for comments or thoughts on the situation that may identify any weak points in running the 2 apps on the same system.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is WT? If that is that is some Web Toolkit as Google suggests then you probably don't need it with Qt. Or otherwise there is more work to make them work together when Qt can do HTTP and has other web-related stuff.

Comment: I believe @C. Pea is talking about the [Wt (pronounce Witty) framework](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/), which is a C++ based toolkit for developing web applications.

Comment: Could you update the question, explaining where you ended up?  Did you get Qt+Wt integrated sufficiently using the Github example, or did you take a different approach?

Answer (score 8):

Wt includes an example in the examples directory, wtwithqt, which explains how Wt and Qt can be made to work together. It includes an implemenation of one particular strategy to make Wt fit in Qt's quite specific threadming model.

Comment: Indeed ! And this example can also be [found directly on Github](https://github.com/emweb/wt/tree/master/examples/wtwithqt). It's certainly a good start.